# How can I use Boto3 libray without installation

Tags: python, boto3

I have a situation which I can't use pip to to install any libray on server. How can i import downloaded boto3 library and import to python script? I would likt to use boto3 to access to S3 and SES

environment: Python 2.7

Boto3
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c8/af/54a920ff4255664f5d238b5aebd8eedf7a07c7a5e71e27afcfe840b82f51/boto-2.49.0.tar.gz

Thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific? Why you cannot do a `pip install` on server? May be you cannot do a `sudo pip install`? Did you try `pip install --user`?

Comment: pip is not allowed to be used by management policies (environment constraints)

Comment: you'll then have to do the hard way, untar above :-) Go to the directory and do a `setup.py install`, but that would be lot more involved and may involve things that are not allowed by management policy.. can you not even create virtual environment and do a `pip install` there?